# How to friendly propose a customer to pay a small sum?

Tags: sentence, formality, colloquialisms, speech

In my language I can say something like, "ok I think we can settle for 30 euros, agree?", but without a negative connotation or that you are implying that the amount has been somewhat adjusted.

What are some forms in English to express the same concept?

I can think of "we can make 30 euros" but I am sure there are dozens of nicer, more colloquial and friendly ways to say it.

Comment: So there's no fixed price for something, you're making the price up right there?

Comment: Can you explain the situation where you would need to make such a statement?

Comment: @JohnFeltz exactly!

Comment: "The best price I can  offer is 30 euros" here "best" would imply the best for the buyer.

Comment: [***How does thirty dollars sound to you?***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22how+does+thirty+dollars+sound+to+you%22)

Comment: This question seems to be more about the art of negotiating than the use of English.

Comment: @Mick but still about English.

Comment: Don't choose an answer so fast. Half the English-speaking world hadn't even seen this question yet. Choosing an answer so quickly means it is less likely that you will get other, possibly better answers. Wait at least 24 hours, maybe more. See  http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm making a quote to a customer on the spot, I could say:

> Let's call it 30 dollars.

or

> Let's say 30 dollars.

If a friend and I have been sharing dinner, a conversation could go:

> I'll pick up the check.
>
> No, that's not right - let me pay for my share.
>
> Well you bought me coffee yesterday, so just give me 10 dollars and we'll call it even.

Comment: What I was after is the "call it x" idiomatic expression. Thanks. In my example I used it like: "I think we can call it a couple of tens?". Hopefully It doesn't sound too horrible :)

Comment: Adding "I think" to the start implies doubt and could be interpreted as you thinking the amount is too low - you could say "Let's call it x" or just "Call it x?" either would be better than "I think". Also you'd probably just say 20 instead of a couple of tens.  It's certainly better than what you started with, though! :)